# Visual Studio 2008 Database Addon

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, add-on

I am currently trying out visual studio to access sql server databases instead of using SQL Server Management Studio.

It was a good surprise how easy it is to setup and use a connection do a database and for the moment it has a positive impact on my productivity.

My question is: Is there an addon (or something i can do) to enable intelisense on SQL Queries?

Comment: Some things are just done better in SQL Management Studio - Which is surprising really as both VS and SQLMS are built on the same core.
Why two different sets of tools?

Comment: Adrian: I agree with you. But for the most common programming needs VS will work just fine and there is no need the have another program openned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Gate SQL Prompt integrates into VS 2008, but it costs money...

Edit: [Are there Free SQL Server Mgmt Studio Autocomplete Add-ins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414404/are-there-free-sql-server-mgmt-studio-autocomplete-add-ins)
This may not work in VS though...

Comment: That one would work +1 :) I would prefer a free addon even if it didnt had all those funcions